# Do we need to use useState() for signup even if there is no defaultValue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

First steps on react

I am creating a website in nextjs and there is a signup page for that. In most of the page I am using useState to keep values and use it with API.

But I am not sure that I need that much. I am not using value and defaultValues props. I only use onChange props to set values.

What is your recommendation?

a or b?

a)

```
const values: SignupProps = {
    firstName: "",
    email: "",
    lastName: "",
    notifications: false,
    password1: "",
    password2: "",
    termsConditions: false,
    username: "",
  };
```

b)

```
const [values, setValues] = useState<SignupProps>({
    firstName:"",
    email:"",
    lastName:"",
    notifications:false,
    password1:"",
    password2:"",
    termsConditions:false,
    username:""
  });
```

**I don't want to render all fields again and again. Because I am using the values only for API body.**

I want to get good performance and more stable page.

Comment: Don't have enough code to be sure, but I don't think re-rendering simple 5-6 input fields on change would affect performance. If you want to squeeze out every single bit of performance, you could probably just leave them as uncontrolled components and fetch the values from DOM during form submit action. To answer your question, I would recommend `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, instead of `useState` you can use `useRef` to create references to all of the inputs, and then collect their values before you submit your form. These inputs are called uncontrolled inputs, or inputs whose value is not controlled by a state variable. You don't even need to use the `onChange` method this way. The `useRef` variables don't trigger a re-render, but keep their values between renders.

I've created a demo codesandbox that you can check out: [Uncontrolled Inputs in Next.js](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gracious-wind-8fibtg?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A35%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A21%2C%22startColumn%22%3A35%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A21%7D%5D).

Here's the output after submitting the form:
[image: program output]

Check out the demo and let me know if you need additional help.